# DLNA over SSTP VPN

Tags: vpn, dlna

On my network, I have an SSTP VPN hosted on Windows Server 2008, and minidlna hosted from Ubuntu Server 14.04.

When I connect my client to the VPN (from outside the LAN), everything works fine, apart from my DLNA (minidlna) server.

I've figured out through searching online, that multi-casting may be a problem.

My PPP adapter on the client gets a subnet mask of 255.255.255.255, which may or may not be the problem.

Assuming that the problem is related to the server setup, what do I need to change within RRAS in Server 2008?

Additional info:

I have set up the DHCP forwarder to give the VPN clients their IP addresses for the VPN network

- netmask: 255.255.255.0
- Range: 192.168.0.100 - 192.168.0.200
- DNS: (External DNS)

VPN server config:

- IP: 192.168.0.6, 192.168.0.7
- netmask: 255.255.255.0
- DNS: (External DNS)

Comment: Please add more info about network architecture, IP addresses and masks, and what you have tried and the errors you get. And especially about how you managed to get a subnet mask of 255.255.255.255.

Comment: I believe they are supposed to have the 255.255.255.255 subnet mask, and then you have to configure it to route broadcast packets. This happened automatically, even though my DHCP server gives out the /24 netmask

Comment: Weird: net mask of 255.255.255.255 is a single host mask, so it is no longer a network but only a standalone host. It can be useful in routing tables where the .255 masks are used to specify routing to a single address only instead of a network block, but I can hardly see how this can apply to your case. Please list the IP addresses and net masks of both host and guest, both in the usual network and in the VPN - the guest cannot be reached via the VPN if it doesn't have an IP address in the VPN network.

Comment: Yep, the IP addresses given out are on the same network as the VPN host. I've added this in the post also

Comment: It's very hard to understand your setup, for example the two IP addresses of the VPN server. Unless you can come up with a better description of your setup, it will be hard to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: The VPN has 2 interfaces ... Although only 192.168.0.6 is used for the VPN interface and DHCP relay

Answer (score 0):

What you have now is a so-called point-to-point connection. This is normal and expected with PPP, which is what SSTP encapsulates. Unfortunately, it’s not suited for anything relying on broadcast or multicast by default.

From my personal experience, you’ll want OpenVPN ([Open Source versions here](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html)), using `dev tap`, for reliable Layer 2 VPN mechanics.

Here’s a *basic* example server config:

```
local myhost
port 12345
proto udp
dev tap
ca /path/to/ca.pem
cert /path/to/server-cert.pem
key /path/to/server-key.pem

ifconfig-pool-persist /path/to/ip-pool

server-bridge 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0 10.0.0.10 10.0.0.200

persist-key
persist-tun

client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
```

This config results in all clients being on the same Layer 2 broadcast domain, using the 10.0.0.0/24 subnet with persistent client IPs. This is similar to how most consumer grade internet gateways behave with DHCP.

The client config is fairly straightforward, too:

```
client
proto udp
dev tap

remote myhost 12345

nobind
persist-key
persist-tun

ca /path/to/ca.pem
cert /path/to/client-cert.pem
key /path/to/client-key.pem

ns-cert-type server
```

OpenVPN expects PEM encoded certificates. OpenSSL can convert between the various encodings. The keys should not require passwords, unless you want the client and/or server to ask for them each launch (not suited for automatic startup).

All certificates have to be signed by the same certificate authority. The server certificate has to be a server certificate and vice versa.

This is by no means a complete guide, merely a configuration example. Bridging between physical and virtual networks has to be set up manually, if desired. You should also take care your automatic address assignment responsibilities do not clash (router vs OpenVPN etc).

Comment: Yeah I have previously set up OpenVPN, but I was trying to get an SSTP/PPTP VPN server working in the same way.

Comment: That’s not possible. Although SSTP could, in theory, also tunnel L2TP, Microsoft does not offer this option, as far as I can see.